# 16 bits bit depth

Tags: java, png, color-depth

I have an image viewed in an applet. How do I save the image as 16 bits bit depth png format? I'm using java.

Answer (score 2):

Conversion to 16 bit is not a part of saving the image data. You'll first have to convert the image data itself by copying to to a `BufferedImage` with a 16 bit [`ColorModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/ColorModel.html). Then just save the result as PNG.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your reply. By the way, i refering to 16 bits per component (Red Green Blue). That is 48 bits per pixel. Is it possible to save as 48 bits because i understand that the Java Advanced Imaging library only supports 24 bits tiff. Thank you.

Comment: @user287663: don't really have any experience working with JAI and 48bit images - but this thread http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=64642 suggests that JAI does support them in principle, just not all the operations